# Windows 7 self/auto updating executable

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, exe, auto-update

I've had a custom auto-update feature for my programs ever since Windows 95. It used to work fine, until Vista and then Windows 7. What it basically did was to download the new executable, create a batch file and execute it. The batch file simply waited for parent executable to close (by constantly trying to delete it) and then move/rename the downloaded new one as the old one. And even run the newly downloaded one. This worked fine for years. But Windows 7 doesn't really like me to do that. One thing is that it "knows" the executables are no longer same (even though their names and paths are same).

Is there a way to silently replace an executable with a new one by copying the executable properties/permission to the new one, so that Windows 7 won't complaint about it being a different exe? (Of course I need this for auto-update feature, so I'm open to other approaches as well)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ClickOnce w/ .NET works great for this... Don't know what you mean by windows 7 complaining about the exe however.

Comment: No @dan, .NET is not my thing. By exe I meant a regular Windows .EXE file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the warnings you describe but I have had problems where I placed the update in a separate directory which broke the pinned item in the task bar.

One approach is to have thin loader which is installed once and then loads the updated program into its own memory space. That way it will be identified as the same program if pinned in the task bar.

I'm only familiar with using .NET AppDomain but I assume most other runtimes can do it as well.